# Exception handling not being done from redux action catch block?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux action to execute an api call. For that I have used a try catch block, the catch block is supposed to check for exception and show them in notification.

The react component has the following code to dispatch action:

```
          useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(getData());
          }, []);
```

The action is as follows:

```
          export const getData = () => async (dispatch) => {
            try {
              const res = await getListOfData();
              dispatch(actionDispatch(VIEW_DATA, res.data));
            } catch (ex) {
              console.log("ex", ex); //Getting error here
              dispatch(
                actionDispatch(SHOW_NOTIFICATION, {
                  message:
                    ex.response && ex.response.data
                      ? ex.response.data.message
                      : "Failed to perform action",
                  open: true,
                  type: "error",
                })
              );
            }
          };
```

The middleware in the backend checks if the token hasn't expired and if it has it redirects user to the login page along with sending 401 error. Now the issue is that I am getting the response in the network tab but upon consoling the exception I get the following error:

[image]

However in the network tab it shows the correct response as follows:

[image]

Why am I getting the invalid hook error in console? Any clue

Comment: In what file are you trying to use the ```useEffect()``` hook. Hooks can only be used inside a functional component as stated in the error. Are you maybe trying to use it inside a class based component some other function?

Comment: It sounds like the error is probably in your middleware?